# recursive backtracking - python. not returning value

Tags: python, recursion, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

**Problem**

I am aware that somewhere in my function, I am not returning something I should.

I am returning the recursive call, but it appears that I am not returning "all the way out"

**Context**

I am doing a depth first search of every single combination in a list. Once I reach a combination that reaches a condition, I want to return.

I am maintaining "state" of my combination and am backtracking where I should be (I think).

What am I doing wrong?

```
class Combo:
    def __init__(self, list):
       self.staples = list
```

Combo has a property called "staples", consisting of a list of staple classes. I want to iterate over the list of staples in a decision tree to find an optimal number.

In this case, the optimal number is summed across the quantities of each staple instance in the list and stored/recalculated as a property on the Combo instance.

```
def IterateStaples(combo, target):        
  #Exit condition for combo dictionary
  if all(combo.diff[macro] < 2 for macro in combo.diff):    
    return combo;                            

  #iterate through all items in list
  for staple in combo.staples:                                  

    #Increment and calc conditions
    staple.increment()         
    combo.calcTotals()      
    combo.findDiff(target)

    #If exceeds target value, backtrack
    if combo.findConflict(target):                
      staple.decrement()
      combo.calcTotals()                
      combo.findDiff(target)              

    #Redundant exit condition to try and return
    elif all(combo.diff[macro] < 2 for macro in combo.diff):                                  
      return combo                

    #Recursive call
    else:        
      return IterateStaples(combo, target)
      staple.decrement()
      combo.calcTotals()
      combo.findDiff(target)
```

Comment: This code is very difficult to understand without knowing what the `combo` and `staples` objects are.

Comment: Good feedback thank you. I will edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly (which is more difficult than usual, since you've not shown what most of the methods you're calling on `combo` and `staple` are), this should be what you want:

```
def IterateStaples(combo, target):        
    # base case
    if all(combo.diff[macro] < 2 for macro in combo.diff): # iterate on combo.diff.values()?
        return combo   # returning combo indicates success!

    for staple in combo.staples:
        staple.increment()                 # update state   
        combo.calcTotals()      
        combo.findDiff(target)

        if not combo.findConflict(target):  # skip recursing on invalid states
            result = IterateStaples(combo, target)    # recursive case
            if result is not None:      # if the recursion was successful, return the result
                return result

        staple.decrement()  # otherwise, undo the change to the state (backtrack)
        combo.calcTotals()     # these two lines might not be necessary when backtracking
        combo.findDiff(target) # since other branches will call them after staple.increment()

    return None # if we got to the end of the loop, explicitly return None to signal failure
```

The `return None` at the end is not strictly necessary, since `None` is the default return value if you don't return anything else. I just think that it's better to be explicit about it.

I'm following your code in returning `combo` on success (and extending it to returning `None` on failure). Since the code mutates `combo` in place, you could just as well return `True` for success (in the base case at the top of the function) and `False` for failure (at the bottom of the function, after the end of the loop). The recursive logic would pass on `True` results, and backtrack after `False` results. The top-level caller would need to check the `combo` instance they'd passed in for the actual solution if they got a `True` return value:

```
combo = Combo(something)
if IterateStaples(combo, target):
    do_stuff(combo) # success!
```

Comment: Hmm. I just tested it and it failed my unittests. It seems as though while it finds a solution, the mutated "combo" instance is not accurate. Will debug and keep you updated

Comment: Moved the base case to the bottom. Upon initialization, I immediately exited because I hadn't calculated diff (diff is initialized to 0)

Comment: I can't really help you with any of that stuff, since I have no idea what `calcTotals`, `findDiff` or the `increment` and `decrement` methods do. If you want a complete answer, you need to ask a complete question.

Comment: haha no problem. I have an issue now with the algo timing out. If I can't figure it out I'll ask a more complete question! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your first `if` statement inside the `for` loop doesn't return anything. What it *should* return depends on your algorithm's logic:

```
#If exceeds target value, backtrack
if combo.findConflict(target):                
   staple.decrement()
   combo.calcTotals()                
   combo.findDiff(target)
   return SOMETHING
```

Additionally, the last 3 lines won't ever get executed, they're **after** the `return` statement.

Comment: Since I'm iterating over a collection and this branch of the decision tree is not useful to me, do I need to return something?

I initially had a function call rather than a return in the last 4 lines.

I am trying your suggestions now though.

Comment: "*this branch of the decision tree is not useful to me*" doesn't work for recursive algorithms. If an iteration relies on the result of a nested call, that nested call **must** return a relevant result.

Comment: @Amit Your answer makes the for loop useless, as it always exit the function at the first iteration

Answer (score 0):

I was able to pass my own test case by incorporating a helper function in the following:

Is this not backtracking? I implemented N-queens with a similar approach

```
def IterateStaples(combo, target):        
  #iterate through all items in list
  bestCombo = []
  def helper(combo):
    for staple in combo.staples:                                      
      #Increment and calc conditions
      staple.increment()         
      combo.calcTotals()      
      combo.findDiff(target)    

      #If exceeds target value, backtrack
      if combo.findConflict(target):                      
        staple.decrement()
        combo.calcTotals()                
        combo.findDiff(target)                                        

      #Redundant exit condition to try and return
      elif all(combo.diff[macro] < 2 for macro in combo.diff):                                          
        bestCombo.append(deepcopy(combo))        
        return                

      #Recursive call
      else:        
        helper(combo)
        staple.decrement()
        combo.calcTotals()
        combo.findDiff(target)

  helper(combo)  

  return bestCombo
```